# XAML in Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I was giving an interview for a company and I was told by the architect that they are creating iOS apps from Xamarin.iOS ( NOT Xamarin Forms) with MvvmCross framework and they use storyboards for UI. But if the UI is very simple they use XAML to create them.

I never knew we can use XAML for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Droid. We had a small discussion/argument if that's even possible. He said they were using it successfully.

My question, is it really possible to use XAML in Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Droid. Because, if we can do that, I feel no use of using Xamarin forms.
If yes, can anyone provide some kind of documentation?

Thank you.

Comment: Only Forms supports XAML.  Android uses AXML, iOS uses native iOS design surfaces or storyboards.  All three can build UI via code.

Comment: Yeah even I though so, but he was so sure and said he is doing that in his project, I thought I might have missed some great Xamarin features.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to design UI in XAML using Xamarin.Android or Xamarin.iOS, but you can include Xamarin.Forms page in Xamarin.Android or Xamarin.iOS app. This way you can have native app with UI using storyboards, but with some Xamarin.Forms pages designed in XAML.

There is a sample how to do that in [Xamarin Forms samples project on GitHub](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Native2Forms).

Comment: I think I did not understand you. Your seem to contradict yourself. No way to design UI in XAML using Xamarin.Android or Xamarin.iOS but can include xamarin.forms page? Xamarin.forms page is in XAML itself so in a way we can right?

Comment: We can mix Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Android/Xamarin.iOS in one application, so part of application will be designed in native way (Storyboards/axml) and part in XAML. You can see example in linked sample project. This way we can include XAML layout in Xamarin.Android/iOS app.

Answer (score 1):

Only Xamarin Forms support sharing of UI via XAML.

UI for iOS has to be made using xib or storyboard. 
For Android using AXML. 
Windows Phone, UWP, WinPhone Silverlight, Windows can use XAML for UI.